# Trying to access OS400/DB2 Stored Procedure Output Parameters from Java with Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, db2, jdbctemplate

Trying to access OS400/DB2 Stored Procedure Output Parameters from Java with Spring JdbcTemplate.  My Stored Procedure last parameter is a input/out parameter if the record is updated I will get back "Y" from the main frame.  Can someone please give me a close on how to access the 2nd parameter and see if it is a "Y"

```
XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("as400.xml"));
DataSource ds = (DataSource) beanFactory.getBean("dataSource");
jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
int res= jdbc.update("{CALL TESTONE(?,?)}", new Object[] { new String("JOHN"), new String("N") });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get back the values from a stored procedure, you need to create your own class that extends `StoredProcedure`, declare your parameters, and then examine the out parameters that are returned from the `execute` call:

```
public final class MyProc extends StoredProcedure {

    public MyProc() {
        super(myDataSource, "TESTONE");
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("param1", Types.CHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("param2", Types.CHAR));
    }

    public String execute(Map<?, ?> inParams) {
        Map results = super.execute(inParams);
        return (String) results.get("param2");
    }
}
```

Comment: so I can't use JdbcTemplate?? and what if the last para is a input and output?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  JdbcTemplate doesn't support examining the values of out parameters.  For an in/out parameter, `declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter(...))` instead

Comment: the line.  Map<String, Object> results = Cast.toMap(super.execute(inParams)); does not work :(

Comment: @john - Sorry, I left a bit of our custom code in there.  I've updated the answer.